# Did Saitama have some level of superhuman strength before training?

Tags: one-punch-man

In his encounter with Crablante before he started training, Saitama is hit by him and thrown away like 30 meters or more, and then hit again 2 more times with those gigantic claws Crablante has. If Saitama was a regular human, how could he support this beating and still stand like it was nothing and fight back?

Comment: 100 push-ups a day was a challenging workout for him starting out, so he was probably not strong enough to be considered superhuman.

Answer (score 1):

Saitama didn't have the level of superhuman strength as currently back before his training started. But he did indeed have the caliber to fight with the presence of his mind.

He spent some time chit-chatting with Crablante until he found a weak spot in his body to attack. He made a tight loop from his tie and got it wound tightly around his tentacular eye. In this way, he pulled out his eye from its place and a huge rush of blood that followed killed Crablante.

From the [One-Punch Man Wiki](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Crablante#History):

> Crablante later appears in a park and discovers a ball-chinned kid, his target. As Crablante is about to finish the boy off, Saitama rushes in and saves the boy. It is revealed that Crablante wants revenge on the kid for defacing his body while he was sleeping in the park by drawing nipples on his chest in permanent ink. Crablante demands that Saitama either surrenders the boy or dies himself. Hearing this, Saitama bursts into a fit of laughter and quips that Crablante reminds him of a villain from an old anime that he used to watch in his childhood (possibly Crab Demon from "Justice Man"). Saitama reveals that his childhood dream was to become a superhero who could defeat villains like Crablante in a single punch. After a brief but intense fight, Saitama defeats Crablante by pulling out an eyestalk along with his internal organs, disemboweling the monster.